# android: double onclicklistener exit

Tags: android

I am writing an app where I have a map with a marker that the user drops
and I thought of this method to delete the markers that the user doesn't want: First you click on an icon and then click the marker and the marker gets deleted. The problem that I am having is that after the initial click on the icon all the markers get deleted on click. I need a way to get out of the `OnClickListener`. I tried `return;` but it didn't work.

```
      mDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.Im_delete);
      mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked Delete icon");
            deleteMarker();
            return;
            }
       });
       private void deleteMarker(){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click a marker to delete it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.remove();
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: why dont you count the number of clicks. Increment integer click and if it is 2 then delete it

Comment: it would count the clicks on all the marker though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text description is not so clear, but let point some changes I think you can do:

1. On the public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) you should return true to avoid the default behaviour once you are deleting the marker.
2. I think you should add the setOnMarkerClickListener outside the method deleteMarker and, to avoid the user delete the marker when clicking on it, you can use a boolean flag (mDeleteMode).
3. Using the mDeleteMode flag you will set it true when the user clicks on mDelete and sets it to false when, for exemple, a) the user deletes a marker, b) clicks outside or c) clicks again on mDelete.

```
public class yourClass {
```

```
    private boolean mDeleteMode = false;

    protected void yourMethod(View view...) {
        mDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.Im_delete);
        mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked Delete icon");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                    "Click a marker to delete it", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mDeleteMode = true;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (mDeleteMode) {
                    mDeleteMode = false;
                    marker.remove();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: @AntreasPapavasiliou if the answer helped you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside it.